# Dictionary error argument of type 'instance' is not iterable

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I am creating a user login/register module for tkinter and am testing it out but I am getting this error when I try to log in by passing two strings to a user dictionary:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'instance' is not iterable
```

Why does this happen? I think that both of the variables are strings...

Here is the module code:

```
import pickle
from Tkinter import *

class LoginBox:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Label(parent, text="Username:").grid()
        self.ubox=Entry(parent)
        self.ubox.grid()
        Label(parent, text="Password:").grid()
        self.pbox=Entry(parent, show="*")
        self.pbox.grid()

    def check(self, userlist):
        pswrd=self.pbox.get()
        uname=self.ubox.get()
        if uname in userlist and userlist[uname] == pswrd:
            return True
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Incorrect", "Incorrect username or password")
            self.pbox.delete(0, "end")


class RegisterBox:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Label(parent, text="Username:").grid()
        self.uname=Entry(parent)
        self.uname.grid()
        Label(parent, text="Password:").grid()
        self.pswrd=Entry(parent, show="*")
        self.pswrd.grid()

    def check(self, userlist):
        pswrd=self.pswrd.get()
        uname=self.uname.get()
        if uname in userlist.users and userlist.users[uname] == pswrd:
            return False
        else:
            userlist.adduser(uname, pswrd)

class UserList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.users={}

    def adduser(self, user, pswrd):
        self.users[user] = pswrd

    def deluser(user):
        del self.users[user]
```

Here is my app code:

```
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import loginutility as lu

root=Tk()

def check():
    if logbox.check() == True:
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Success", "Good job!")

users=lu.UserList()

regbox=lu.RegisterBox(root)
Button(root, text="Register", command=lambda: regbox.check(users)).grid()
logbox=lu.LoginBox(root)
Button(root, text="Login", command=check).grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It will help if u mention line where u get this error

Comment: always show full error message. There is line number and other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check user and login in different way in `RegisterBox` and `LoginBox`.

`userlist` is not normal dictionary but class `UserList` and you have to use `userlist.users` and `userlist.users[uname]` in `LoginBox.check()`.

-

btw: you could create `UserList.check(user,password)`

Comment: Thanks! Will do what you suggest. Might make it easier.